# Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.profileImageUrl'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie to firebase and Javascript and I have tried many methods to get the user data store by the `user.uid` but all I'm getting is the data is being stored under "undefined".

Screenshot of uRef?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga19e.png

Here is screenshots of error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiY4e.png

> Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.profileImageUrl'

---

Here is the code:

```
var displayName;<br>
var userInfo;<br>
var profile_url;<br>

   $("#login-btn").click(function(){<br>
     userInfo = firebase.auth().currentUser;<br>
     if (userInfo) { <br>
       firebase.auth().signOut(); <br>
     } else { <br>
       var email = document.getElementById('login_email').value; <br>
       var password = document.getElementById('login_pw').value; <br>

       firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(){
         document.getElementById('login_bar').style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById('logout_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
         document.getElementById('userinfo_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
         document.getElementById('secession_bar').style.display = "inline-block";
         alert("login success");
         location.replace('board.html');
       }).catch(function(error) {

         var errorCode = error.code;
         var errorMessage = error.message;

         if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
           alert('wrong-password.');
         }

         else {
           alert(errorMessage);
         }
         console.log(errorMessage);

       }); 


     } 

   });

   $("#join-btn").click(function(){ <br>
     var email = document.getElementById('join_email').value;<br>
     var password = document.getElementById('join_pw').value;<br>
     var displayName = document.getElementById('join_name').value;<br>
     var job = $('input[name=job]:checked').val();<br>

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {<br>

      var u_Ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);

      userInfo = user;

      u_Ref.set({
        'email' : email,
        'job': job,
        'profileImageUrl':profile_url,
        'uid' : user.uid,
        'username': displayName
      });


        handleFileSelect(); 
        alert("join success");

    }, function(error) {<br>
  var errorCode = error.code;<br>
  var errorMessage = error.message;<br>
  alert(error);<br>
});<br>

     if (email.length < 4) {
       alert('x');
       return;
     }
     if (password.length < 4) {
       alert('x');
       return;
     }

    function initApp() {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) { 
          var displayName = user.displayName;
          var email = user.email;
          var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
          var photoURL = user.photoURL;
          var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
          var uid = user.uid;
          var providerData = user.providerData;

          user.updateProfile ({
            displayName : displayName,

          }). then (function () {
            console.log ( 'success');
          }). catch (function (error) {
            console.log( 'no');
          });

          userInfo = user;

          firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION); 
          document.getElementById('login_bar').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('logout_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
          document.getElementById('userinfo_bar').style.display = "inline-block";
          document.getElementById('secession_bar').style.display = "inline-block";


          $("#secession_bar").click(function(){
            user.delete().then(function(){ 
              alert('success');
             userRef= firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
             userRef.remove(); 
             firebase.storage().ref().child('userImages/' + userInfo.uid).delete(); 
            location.reload();
            });
          });

          $("#logout_bar").click(function(){
            firebase.auth().signOut();
            location.reload();
          });



        } else { 

          document.getElementById('login_bar').style.display = "inline-block"; 
          document.getElementById('logout_bar').style.display = "none"; 
          document.getElementById('userinfo_bar').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('secession_bar').style.display = "none";



        } 

      });
    } 

    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      evt.preventDefault();
      var file = evt.target.files[0];

      var metadata = {
        'contentType': file.type
      };


      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('userImages/' +userInfo.uid);

      storageRef.put(file, metadata).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded', snapshot.totalBytes, 'bytes.');
        console.log('File metadata:', snapshot.metadata);

        snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
          console.log('File available at', url);
          profile_url = url;

        });
      }).catch(function(error) {

        console.error('Upload failed:', error);

      });

    }
```

---

I fixed it but got the same error
[image]

[image]

Not undefined here

Comment: Please don't post images of textual content. Instead post the actual exact textual contents of the error message (including its stack trace) directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear:

> First argument contains undefined in property 'users.undefined.profileImageUrl'

You're passing `undefined` as value in `users.undefined.profileImageUrl`, which is not allowed. The most likely location that raises this error is:

```
  u_Ref.set({
    'email' : email,
    'job': job,
    'profileImageUrl':profile_url,
    'uid' : user.uid,
    'username': displayName
  });
```

And here the most likely reason is that `profile_url` hasn't been initialized yet, since you haven't uploaded an image yet,

The simplest fix is to only set the `profileImageUrl` if `profile_url` has a value, which you can most easily do by splitting this into two sets:

```
  u_Ref.set({
    'email' : email,
    'job': job,
    'uid' : user.uid,
    'username': displayName
  });
  if (profile_url) {
    u_Ref.child('profileImageUrl').set(profile_url)
  }
```

I guess you'll also want to set the `profile_url` if the image upload finishes later, so you might want to do something like:

```
snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log('File available at', url);
  profile_url = url;
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if (user && user.uid) {
    var u_Ref = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
    u_Ref.child('profileImageUrl').set(profile_url)
  }
});
```